# compile input pdf from tex file prior to pdfpages

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

Is it possible to generate pdfs from tex files prior to using pdfpages for files that will be included in the output pdf? I would like to generate the input pdfs when compiling the main pdf. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% create pdf from file1.tex here
% create pdf from file2.tex here

\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge{file1.pdf}
\includepdfmerge{file2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a couple of make/automation tools which are capable to do this. Which editor do you use?

Comment: `\immediate\write18{pdflatex file1}\immediate\write18{pdflatex file2}` where the commented lines are.

Comment: I am using TeXstudio, but ideally the files would be able to be compiled using any tex compiler.

Comment: I tried inserting \immediate\write18{pdflatex file1}\immediate\write18{pdflatex file2}, but got the error "Cannot find file 'file1.pdf'\includepdfmerge.pdf"

Comment: I needed to add % !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]  at the top of my main .tex file. Then, \immediate\write18{..} worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Texstudio (and other editors which accept magic comments) you could add the following line at the begin of your file

```
 % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex file1 | pdflatex file2 | pdflatex %
```

to first compile all three files

Or use `latexmk` instead of `pdflatex`, then it will automatically detect if something changed and the files need to be recompiled or just use the existing ones:

```
% !TeX TS-program = latexmk file1 file2 %
```